# How to create educational linear algebra animations?

Tags: linear-algebra, education

I'm looking to create animations for a linear algebra course. I need things like writing and changing equations, including matrices, plotting of 2- and 3-dimensional axes with points, vectors, lines and planes, and so on. The intention is to incorporate the animations into a separate video, to demonstrate and visualize what's being said.

How can I go about creating such animations? I'm ideally looking for a free solution.

I'm aware of 3Brown1Blue's youtube channel and vPython package, but I'm looking for other options. Mostly because I don't like working with vPython.

Comment: See [mathematics educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/). You'll get better answers there, than here.

Comment: Thank you, I will do that. I wasn't aware that it existed.

Comment: You may try [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/).

Comment: please migrate to math educators. I'm skipping close vote on this, as should all.

Comment: I have no idea how to migrate; I posted the question on math educators.